3D plot labels exceed subplot limits - Matplotlib
For 2D plots, using constrained or tight layout is generally enough to adjust the size of the axes to fit labels, but none of the default layouts manages to do it for small 3D plots like the one shown below. I've been trying to read about transforms to see if I could manually scale down the axes, but I have never used them before and am struggling to understand how to apply them.
Is there a way to reduce the size of a 3D plot to prevent its labels from exceeding the limits of the subplot?
MWE
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == "__main__":

    x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)
    y = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)
    z = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)

    fig = plt.figure(facecolor="green", layout="constrained", figsize=(3, 3))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="3d", proj_type="ortho")
    ax.scatter(x, y, z)
    plt.show()



In this case it is usually dependent on the machine you are running also. However to enable that the padding is right you can try setting tight_layout  to squeeze everything within the white region. Adding these two lines before the plt.show() method worked for me.
    fig.set_tight_layout(True)
    plt.tight_layout()

Setting a tight layout brings the image to fit within the bounds or the figure area. You can also play with the paddings if you want as arguments in tight_layout() method. I have attached the link to the documentation here.

None of the layouts work for me. Paddings also seem to be doing nothing, which is weird.

Can you elaborate on what platform you are evaluating this? Did you try expanding the window size of the plot to see if it still shows the issue? Sometimes it can be platform specific issue such as the IDE or system you are using. However his should work.
